# Vaadin Flow .war static resources in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, vaadin, vaadin-flow

### Context

I have a Vaadin Flow Spring Boot project, using Vaadin 14 in compatibility mode, which is packaged as an executable .war file using Gradle (so with the Gradle `war` plugin). I have some static resources, which are in `src/main/webapp/frontend/styles`.  I'm using development mode for the time being.  Due to other constraints I can't turn off compatibility mode for the forseeable future.

I know that [this page](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/importing-dependencies/tutorial-ways-of-importing.html#resource-cheat-sheet) advises to use `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources` for Spring projects, but that is probably because Spring Boot defaults to .jar layout.  For .war layouts static resources should go in (subfolders of) `src/main/webapp`.

Building the .war file using gradle and then running it outside the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), everything is fine.

### Issue

Running the Spring Boot service in IntelliJ IDEA, static resources from `src/main/webapp` are not found.  The requests all return 404 with a similar message:

```
Could not navigate to 'frontend/styles/images/logo.png'
Reason: Couldn't find route for 'frontend/styles/images/logo.png'

Available routes:
  . <root>
  . ... (listing routes for all my application views)

This detailed message is only shown when running in development mode.
```

### Things I've tried for debugging this

I've tried putting some resources directly under `src/main/webapp` because I know Vaadin does special things with the `frontend` folder, but these give the same error.

If I change the build file to use a `jar` layout, and move the files to `src/main/resources`, everything is fine.  Unfortunately due to other constraints I need to keep the `war` layout.

I've created a simple non-Vaadin Spring Boot application with `war` layout and it doesn't have any issues serving static resources from 'src/main/webapp' when run inside Intellij IDEA.  It seems to be Vaadin not understanding that I'm requesting a static resource instead of a route, maybe because it doesn't realize that the `war` layout is being used.

***Update***

When debugging, I noticed that the following method is called in `VaadinServletService` with argument `frontend/styles/images/logo.png`:

```
@Override
public URL getStaticResource(String path) {
    try {
        return getServlet().getServletContext().getResource(path);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        getLogger().warn("Error finding resource for '{}'", path, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And the result of `getServlet().getServletContext().getResource(path)` is `null`.  As Vaadin thinks it's not a static resource, it tries to resolve it as a route.

I've tried putting the resources in the path where they'd have to be when the .jar layout would be used, which is `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/styles`.  This works: they get picked up when running in IntelliJ, confirming my belief that the app thinks it's running as a .jar.  But as I'm using the .war layout it's not the correct folder for packaging, and obviously I don't want to put the resources in both locations in order to run the app locally and get it packaged correctly as a .war.

Comment: Have you tried the `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources`? As you have a Spring boot project in a compatibility mode, it should be used instead [Recource Cheat Sheet](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/importing-dependencies/tutorial-ways-of-importing.html#resource-cheat-sheet)

Comment: @anasmi that is the location for .jar layouts

Comment: @anasmi also if the location would be wrong, it wouldn't work when running the.war file outside the IDE.

Comment: How do you reference your static resources?

Comment: @anasmi I found them referenced in 2 ways: 1) annotation `@HtmlImport("frontend://styles/shared-styles.html")`  on a component, 2) for the logo.png example above, it's an `Image` component with the `src` property set to the relative URL `frontend/styles/images/logo.png`.  Both seem not to work in the IDE, both work when running the Gradle generated .war outside the IDE.

Comment: Why is your image in `styles` folder? try `src/main/webapp/img/logo.png` as location and load it with `new Image("img/logo.png", "alt text")`. Additionally, are you using Spring Security?

Comment: @kscherrer why, well because some Vaadin consultant put it there :).  Indeed it's odd, but it works fine as a war.  Also, as mentioned in the question, I've tried putting some resources under `/src/main/webapp` and trying to request them from the browser, but still Vaadin intercepts this request and tries to find a route, which fails.  Yes, Spring Security is used.

Comment: `Yes, Spring Security is used.` - can you please verify that your security configuration (`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`) properly ignores "/frontend/**" and "/img/**"  in the method `public void configure(WebSecurity web)` ? If not sure what I mean, can you post that class?

Comment: @kscherrer, "/img/**" is not ignored, but "/frontend/**" (where the images and other resources are) is.  Also, if this would be the issue I'd think I'd have the same problem when running the executable .war outside IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I gather that since the bounty on this is only three days old, you haven't had any luck resolving the problem since June 23. Is that correct @herman? If you are still open to suggestions, then pushing a simplified, stripped-down [*MRE*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to a repo should get you a satisfactory resolution within the next three-four days. TIA.

Comment: @deduper Indeed I have not.  However creating a stripped-down MRE may take some time which I currently don't have, and may still not allow other people to reproduce the problem as my IntelliJ run configuration, Gradle settings etc. may have an impact as well (my Eclipse colleagues are not impacted by this issue).  Meanwhile I was able to make the problem less severe by switching away from compatibility mode to native Vaadin 14 mode.  Since .css files are now in /frontend folder and imported using `@CssImport`, only images are still broken.  Would still be interested in a resolution though.